# Is it possible to derive $N= \left\lceil R \right\rceil$ from $R\leq N < R+1$ when $R$ positive real number and N is positive integer?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have the following expression

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&R\leq N < R+1
\end{eqnarray*}

where $N$ is a positive integer and $R$ positive real number. Is it correct to derive $N= \left\lceil R \right\rceil$. As we know that $E\leq N< E+1$, we can derived $N=E$ if E is a positive integer.

similarly

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&R-1< N \leq R
\end{eqnarray*}

where $N$ is a positive integer and $R$ positive real number. Is it correct to derive $N=\left\lfloor R \right\rfloor$. As we know that $E-1< N \leq E$, we can derived $N=E$ if E is a positive integer.

Example :

\begin{eqnarray*}
  && x+(N-1+1)\times K \leq y,\\
  && x+(N+1)\times K>  y
\end{eqnarray*}

Is it correct to derive $N=\left\lfloor \frac{y-x}{K} \right\rfloor$ if $x,y,K,N$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clearly formulated, so forgive me if I have misinterpreted it.

There appear to be three similar but separate sub-questions. As the third does not appear to be an "example" of either of the first two, I shall treat the three questions separately.

1. If $N$ is a positive integer, and $R$ is a positive real number, and
   $$
   R \leq N < R + 1,
   $$
   then
   $$
   N - 1 < R \leq N,
   $$
   whence by definition $N = \lceil R \rceil,$ just as you suspected.
2. If $N$ is a positive integer, and $R$ is a positive real number, and
   $$
   R - 1 < N \leq R,
   $$
   then
   $$
   N \leq R < N + 1,
   $$
   whence by definition $N = \lfloor R \rfloor,$ again just as you suspected.
3. If $x, y, K, N$ are positive integers, and
   $$
   x + NK \leq y < x + (N + 1)K,
   $$
   then
   $$
   N \leq \frac{y - x}K < N + 1,
   $$
   and once again you are proved correct, because the definition of the floor function now implies
   $$
   N = \left\lfloor\frac{y - x}K\right\rfloor.
   $$